# Using pointers/references incorrectly?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have multiple maps, and a vector of pointers to maps:

```
map<string, int> one4, one5, one7 ;
vector< map<string, int>*> Maps{ &one4, &one5, &one7 } ;
```

In some function, I have a loop which I'm not sure is correct:

```
for( map<string, int>* x : Maps ) { }
```

I would like to directly access the individual maps and alter the entries inside the loop. For example, I wrote:

```
if( !(x.count( binStr ))) {
    x[ binStr ] = 1 ;
}
```

When compiled with the `make` command, I get the following error:

```
error: request for member ‘count’ in ‘x’, which is of pointer type ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
```

I think I must be using * and & wrong, but I'm not sure how. I haven't coded in C++ much, so please don't be harsh!

Comment: Read the error message carefully, it tells you what to do. `maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?`  `x->count`.

Comment: `.` and`->` are language quirks to make programmers aware of what they are dealing with: Reference or pointer.

Comment: Generally for a pointer variable yes. You may run into problems on the next line as well. `(*x).count(...)` and `(*x)[...]` should be okay. Why do you have a container of pointer to maps anyway? Do the maps have a lifetime that is different from the vector? Do they need to?

Answer (score -1):

When accessing member functions of a pointer variable, you must utilize the *arrow operator* otherwise known as the *indirect member selection operator*.

Using your example:

```
    std::map<std::string, int> one4 {}, one5 {}, one7 {};
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>*> Maps { &one4, &one5, &one7 };

    for( std::map<std::string, int>* x : Maps) {
        std::cout << x->count("Map Key") << std::endl;
        // you can also do the following
        // std::cout << (*x).count("Map Key") << std::endl;
        // dereference the pointer and then apply the direct
        // member selection operator '.'
    }
```